# complex measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to prove something about complex measurable functions. I have an idea for one direction and hope someone can give me a hint, I have gotten somee work done in this direction but need help to close it.

The other direction is a little trickier.

We have one definition:

> Let $(\Omega,A)$  be a measurable space. A complex valued function f
>   on $\Omega$ is said to be a $A$-measurable function if the inverse
>   image of each open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ under f is an A-measurable
>   set, that is if $f^{-1}(O) \in A$ for all open sets $O \subset \Omega.$

Then we have this theorem:

> A complex-valued function f on $\Omega$ is A-measurable if and only if
>   both its real part U, and its imaginary party V(real valued) are
>   A-measurable functions.(f=U+iV).

This theorem is what I want to prove.

$\rightarrow$

First I assume that the function is A-measurable. I need to prove that $U^{-1}(O), V^{-1}(O)$ is A-measurable for any open set $O \in \mathbb{R}$.

So assume we have O in R. It can be written as $O_C \cap \mathbb{R}$, for an open set $O_C$ in the complex plane.We also know that the real line is A-measurable.

Then we have that $(U+i*V)^{-1}(O_C \cap \mathbb{R})$ is measurable. **But how do I use this to show that $U^{-1}(O_C \cap \mathbb{R}),V^{-1}(O_C \cap \mathbb{R})$ is measurable?**

$\leftarrow$

Now I have that for any open set in the real numbers, $U^{-1}(O),V^{-1}(O)$ are measurable.

But to prove this direction I need to start with an open set in the complex numbers $O_C$, and show that $(U+i*V)^{-1}(O_c)$ is measurable.

Do you have any tips on this direction?

Answer (score 6):

I believe the solution is less complicated than you are thinking, mate.

$\gets$

Let $R$ be the rectangle $I_1\times I_2$ where $I_1$ and $I_2$ are open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\space f^{-1}(R)=U^{-1}(I_1)\cap V^{-1}(I_2)$ which is A-measurable since $U^{-1}(I_1)$ and $V^{-1}(I_2)$ are. But every open set in  $\mathbb{R}^2$ (or $\mathbb{C}$) can be written as a countable union of such rectangles. The result follows. (Check this!)

$\to$

Let $pr_i:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{R},\space i=1,2$ be the projections on the first and second coordinate respectively (or the real part and imaginary part if you prefer). These functions are continuous and we have that $U=pr_1\circ f$ and $\space V=pr_2 \circ f$. Therefore, given an open set $O\subset\mathbb{R}$, $\space U^{-1}(O)=f^{-1}(pr_1^{-1}(O))$, which is A-measurable since $pr^{-1}(O)$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$ and $f$ is measurable by hypothesis. So U is A-measurable. Analogously, we prove that V is A-measurable.  QED

I think it would be a nice exercise to try and generalise a bit further this definition of measurability and prove the $\to$ part as a theorem separately.

I hope it helped,

Gregory